# Why this return value? C++ int/char confusion

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Using GNU GCC Compiler 4.8.1. This really simple program has me stuck on something. When prompted for input, it expects an integer for the first value and a character for the second value. If I instead enter a character or any string of text instead of an integer, it always returns unit with a value of the character 'u'.

Can anyone explain why that is the case?

```
int main()
{
const double cm_per_inch = 2.54;
int length = 1;
char unit;
cout << "Please enter a length followed by a unit (c or i): ";
cin >> length;
cin >> unit;
if (unit == 'i')
    cout << length << "in == " << cm_per_inch * length << "cm\n ";

else if (unit == 'c')
    cout << length << "cm == " << length/cm_per_inch << "in\n";

else
    cout << " I don't know a unit called " << unit << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: unit is not initialized and after the stream failure it contains some value (here 'u')

Comment: The first rule of debugging code -- add error checking to all operations. Most of the time, you don't need a second rule.

Comment: This is what happens when you do not check for errors or validate input. Hint: if `cin >> length` fails you do not handle the error and just move on without any consideration for the invalid input.

Comment: Is your program allowed to accept negative numbers?  For example, enter "-2.54 c".

Comment: As that picture only shows a few lines of text (no graphics at all), better copy-and-paste it as text. You can use `<!-- language: none -->` to disable syntax-highlighting for a following code-block.

Comment: Removed the picture, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't initialize `unit`, so if the input fails, it contains whatever random, nonsense value it happened to have. None of your input code tests to see if it succeeds or fails, yet you access the value of `unit` either way. So the results if the input fails are unpredictable garbage.

Try changing:

```
 char unit;
```

to

```
 char unit = '?';
```

Answer (score 3):

One of your issues is that you don't initialize your `unit` variable, so we have no idea what it will print out when your input fails.

You should really check for errors after each input and handle them then:

```
if (cin >> length)
{
  if (cin >> unit)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Inputting of an integer will fail if it encounters a non-integer character.

Comment: No need to check after every input, it's enough to check before any of it is used. The previous error makes the following input-operation a no-op.

Comment: @Deduplicator: If the integer input fails, the unit is not input.  The structure allows for the OP to differentiate between the causes of error;  when tested as "if (cin >> length >> unit)", the cause of the failure is not clear.

Comment: Yes, but most times exactly where it failed is of no interest, only the fact that it did is.